# flyway checksum calculation error on unchanged SQL script

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I got following error when run flyway (flyway-6.0.0) migrate:

```
ERROR: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration version 1.1
-> Applied to database : -1340212107
-> Resolved locally    : -1039259818
```

The SQL script is: V1_1__add_column_location_history_valid_until.sql

```
alter table location_history add column valid_until timestamp with time zone;
```

I run the crc32 check on this file and covert it into signed integer:

```
root@jerry:~# crc32 V1_1__add_column_location_history_valid_until.sql
b01dfc75
root@jerry:~# echo $(( 16#b01dfc75 -2**32 ))
-1340212107
```

I found the checksum is exact same as what have been applied to database.

Now I am very confused why flyway calculate the checksum result -1039259818, which is clearly wrong.

Is this a bug in flyway latest version?

**Problem solved by flyway support.**
 The -1039259818 checksum is produced by both Flyway 5.2.4 and Flyway 6.0. These are both stripping off line endings from the migration. -1340212107 is the checksum of the file with a LF at the end of the single line. A flyway repair should correct everything for you.